# Got permission denied for chromedriver with Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I got tests who run on a raspberry with jenkins and Selenium and it work fine.

I got an industrial computer with Ubuntu on it. I have tests who work with command line. But when I launch it with jenkins either by being the jenkins user or by the Jenkins page it does not work.
To simplify in maximum to know where the issue came from, I made a minimum Selenium test which is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--silent")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
chromedriver_service = Service("/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.close()
```

And I Got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/swof/DPASS_Automation/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/home/swof/DPASS_Automation/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/swof/DPASS_Automation/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/swof/DPASS_Automation/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

When I launch this test by being the main user no error.

I use python3.9 and a venv to have less issue between different user and that works well on the RPi.

I try different thing:

- I add Jenkins to the sudo user by editing /etc/sudoers and add jenkins ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL at the end of the file
- I gave all right to the folder where my project by using chmod -R 777 /folder
- Even if I use a venv I install Selenium with sudo pip install Selenium
- When I use Python shell I can import Selenium without issue, it crash only here: driver = webdriver.Chrome (options=options)
- I try to uninstall and install jenkins

I think it must be with chromium-browser because I got this error when I try to launch it by being the Jenkins user with `chromium-browser`:

> WARNING: cannot start document portal: dial unix /run/user/1000/bus: connect permission denied
> /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice/vte-spawn-99fb6268-be1d-42e8-8b6b-5267c428ebf4.scope is not a snap cgroup

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found a solution.
To sum up he change the home directory of Jenkins.
He creates new directory in /home. Copy all the file from /var/lib/Jenkins to this new directory. He gives access to this directory to Jenkins. Finally, he changes the home location in /etc/default/Jenkins.

It is this tutorial he uses: https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-02-changing-home-directory